# How to deploy smart contract automatically in rinkeby network through web3.js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, dapp-development, rinkeby

I am deploying a DAPP in which after getting the inputs from the users I have to deploy a smart contract in Rinkeby test network.

After getting the inputs from a user I am writing the `.sol` file using Nodejs and storing it in Amazon EC2 instance. Now, how will I deploy this contract in Rinkeby network?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have already written a smart contract with Solidity, you should compile and deploy that to Rinkeby. You could use web based [Solidity IDE "Remix"](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.18+commit.9cf6e910.js) for this.

Then your web app (DAPP) could interact with your smart contract using [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) while sitting on EC2 instance.